# Complex Google Sheets find, search and build array

Tags: arrays, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Thank you @TheWizEd, your tips and guidance are sincerely appreciated. I am in a learning phase and your suggested code and tips have me on a much improved learning path.

UPDATED FOCUS, @TheWizEd provided a very helpful script for me to study and play with, but to hone in the focus, I would like to know if it’s possible to write the Nickname comma separated results to the respective Results column row.

Original Post:
I've been studying Google Sheets functions, and I managed to get `REPLACE()`, `REGEXMATCH()`, and other various Google Sheets functions working to achieve what I am trying to do on a record-by-record, row-by-row basis, but searching, grouping and replacing data has proven very difficult. I've done my best to completely break down the problem below.

The Google Sheet has three columns: (A) *Text String*, (B) *Email* and (C) *Data Output*. I have 10,000+ rows, sorted by the *Email*. This keeps them easily grouped for visual and manual editing.

Some rows have multiple instances with the same *Email*, but the data in *Text String* is variable.

Example:

Row 1: "The brown fox jumps through the hoop", "joe@joe.com", ""
Row 2: "The red fox stands tall", "joe@joe.com", ""
Row 3: "The yellow fox sits at the table", "joe@joe.com", ""
.
.
.
10,000 rows

What I am trying to automate:

1. Searching the *Text String* column (A), where *Email* (column B) is the same (one or many instances)
2. Based on findings, from a pre-defined set of strings (see examples below) in *Text String* (A):
3. Build data output array string to *Data Output* (column C) to the first instance row of *Email*
4. Delete all rows except the first or only instance of *Email* that contains the newly written data array string (C)

As noted in step 2 above, here are some examples of strings searched and newly written  into *Data Output* array (column C):

if "hoop" exists in row, add to output array "hoopus,"
if "brown" exists in row, add to output array "browny,"
if "sits" exists in row, add to output array "sity,"
if "slowly" exists in row, add to output array "slow,"
if "stands tall" exists in row, add to output array "tall,"
if "red fox" exists in row, add to output array "rf,"

Final output example:

Row 1: "The brown fox jumps through the hoop", "joe@joe.com", "hoopus, browny, sity, tall, rf"
Row 2: "The red fox stands tall", "joe@joe.com", "" (DELETED) 
Row 3: "The yellow fox sits at the table", "joe@joe.com", "" (DELETED)

The order that the array string is written to *Data Output* is **not** important.
The last word in array string should not have a comma after it.

Thank you in advance for any insights or code samples, **if in fact the above is even possible!**

Comment: if you include more realistic text strings so that we understand the goal of your marketing/ mail-merge thing, it'll be easier to help?  

You can use this form to make an anonymous sheet in which to paste some sample data to make your question easier to understand.
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform

Comment: @MattKing Thank you for setting me in the right direction on problem presentation. And sounds like you know exactly what I am trying to do in regards to fixing an email list. Typically when I am having difficulty grasping a complex concept, I like to explain it in other words as it helps be better think with the problem. I posted the data sample to the Google Sheet you suggested.

Comment: [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. Questions asked here should be self contained. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet. [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Exact copy of [Automation possibility and script of find, then add-to-array and write to row](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/169736567).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

It may be possible with regex but that's too complicated for me.  Instead here is an example script.

I made up a spreadsheet with data and the key/value table as shown below.

[image]

Code.gs

```
function test() {
  try {
    let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let range = sheet.getRange(2,1,5,3); // A2:D6 but can be extendes
    let data = range.getValues();
    let keys = sheet.getRange(10,1,6,2).getValues();
    let email = data[0][1];
    let row = 0;
    let words = [];
    for( let i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) {
      if( data[i][1] !== email ) {
        email = data[i][1]
        words = [...new Set(words)].toString();
        data[row][2] = words;
        row = i;
        words = [];
      }
      keys.forEach( (key,j) => { if( data[i][0].indexOf(key[0]) >= 0 ) {
                                    words.push(key[1])
                                  }
                               }
                  );
    }
    words = [...new Set(words)].toString();
    data[row][2] = words;
    
    // remove duplicate emails
    data = data.filter( row => row[2] !== "" );
    console.log(data)

    range.clearContent();
    sheet.getRange(2,1,data.length,3).setValues(data);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
4:34:06 PM  Notice  Execution started
4:34:08 PM  Info    [ [ 'The red fox chases the dog', 'mary@mary.com', 'rf,sity' ],
  [ 'The brown fox jumps through the hoop', 'joe@joe.com', 'hoopus,browny,tall,rf,sity' ],
4:34:07 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**Reference**

- [Set Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)
- [Array.forEach()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_foreach.asp)
- [String.indexOf()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful suggestions on script. Do you know if it’s possible to write the Nickname words to the Results column in the sheet?

Comment: I have updated my script to place the result back to the spreadsheet.